# 1999 Putnam A-5 as a direct result of Archimedean Property

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math

I was working on question A-5 from the 1999 Putnam Exam:

Prove that there is a constant C such that, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree 1999, then
$|p(0)|≤C\int_{-1}^1|p(x)|dx$

This seemed like a direct consequence of the Archimedean Property of the reals to me, since the value of the integral must be a finite, positive real number, and the lefthand side is a finite, nonnegative real number. However, all of the solutions (they gave 3: see this page http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/) were much more complicated; is there a case I am missing by merely viewing this as a result of the Archimedean property? Or is there some missing condition that makes it not applicable for this problem?

Comment: You're asked to prove that the *same* constant $ C $ works for *every* polynomial of degree $ 1999 $. How does that follow from the Archimedean property?

Comment: Your solution will provide a $C$ given some polynomial $p(x)$, but the question wants a single value $C$ that works for all polynomials

Comment: I cannot at all see what the Archimedean property has do with this problem at all. Does your argument give a **value** for $C$?

Comment: starfall hit the nail right on the head.

Comment: The problem requires a single constant $C$ to work for *all* $p$.  It would be equivalent to say: prove $\{ |p(0)| / \int_{-1}^1 |p(x)| \, dx : \mathrm{deg}(p) = 1999 \}$ is bounded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to let $\mathcal P$ denote the set of polynomials of degree $\le 1999.$ Then $\mathcal P$ is a vector space (say over $\mathbb R$) of dimension $2000.$ On this vector space we can introduce two norms:

$$\|p\|_1 = \sum_{k=0}^{1999} |p(k)|,\,\, \|p\|_2 = \int_{-1}^1 |p(x)|\, dx.$$

It's easy to check that these are indeed norms on $\mathcal P.$ So we have two norms on a finite dimensional vector space. A standard result says any two norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent. It follows that there is a constant $C$ such that

$$\|p\|_1 \le C\|p\|_2\,\, \text { for all } p\in \mathcal P.$$

Since $|p(0)| \le \|p\|_1,$ we've proved the result.

I wonder if this answer would satisfy the Putnam overlords.

Comment: That was really a very smart approach. I am not so familiar with the result concerning norms of vector spaces. Will have a look at it. +1

Answer (score 0):

Posting this because I can't comment:

The norm trick would work for a lot of similar Putnam questions. That's why in recent years they ask you to find C explicitly, not just prove it exists.